# Header customizado angular 4, erro não autentica

Tags: angular

Bom dia, estou precisando fazer conectar em um servico que requer autenticação passando alguns headers, mais de todas as maneiras que tentei, não envia o meu Header customizado, segue abaixo o código:

```
public listarCategorias(): Observable<category[]> {

    return this.http.get<category[]>('https://xxxxx/categories')
        .pipe(
        tap(heroes => { this.log(`listarCategorias`) }),
        catchError(this.handleError('listarCategorias', []))
        );
}
```

Fiz um Interceptor

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-accountmanager-key': 'xxxx',
        'x-api-key': 'xxxx',
        'x-user-email': 'xxxx',

    }

    const clone = req.clone({
        setHeaders: headers
    });

    return next.handle(clone);
}
```

Testei em vários aplicativos como ARC, e a autentica normalmente.

o Header que capturei no navegador foi o seguinte:

> :method:OPTIONS :path:/categories :scheme:https accept:*/*
>   accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
>   accept-language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
>   access-control-request-headers:content-type,x-accountmanager-key,x-api-key,x-user-email
>   access-control-request-method:GET origin:http://localhost:4200
>   user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94
>   Safari/537.36

[image: Teste no comentario abaixo]

Arnaldo R. Portela, alterei seu exemplo, e não foi, quando executo no ARC, vai

Answer (score 0):

Eu recriei seu exemplo no plnkr e funcionou, confira no link se a minha implementação se encontra diferente da sua:

[Link do exemplo](https://plnkr.co/edit/qH9S2u9YQdIMmVPCzFgB?p=info)

Apenas lembrando que como você está utilizando o HttpInterceptor, você deve utilizar a classe "HttpClient" que está em "@angular/common/http" para realizar os requests e não a classe "Http" que está em "@angular/http".

Editado: ele manda duas requisições, um OPTIONS e em seguida um GET, no exemplo que eu coloquei, os headers estão sendo alterados e o retorno está OK. Claro que eu não estou colocando um bearer e não estou fazendo nenhuma autenticação, mas as informações do header estão lá.

[image: Exemplo]

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela ajuda..., mais mesmo assim, até no seu exemplo da 401, e quando testo no ARC da certo... quando coloco o interceptor no header fica :method:OPTIONS, será que esse é o erro?

Comment: Boa Tarde, fiz um exemplo também, com as informações corretas, segue o link: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/hu9ZspfwwRXHExzFaoW6?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Aconteceu algo parecido no meu projeto, mas depois percebi que era a versão das minhas dependências, dentro da pasta raiz do teu projeto executa

```
ng --version
```

E posta o aparece.

Comment: @angular/cdk: 5.0.0-rc0
@angular/cli: 1.5.0
@angular/material: 5.0.0-rc0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.32
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.20
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.35
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.2
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1